# hosting providers assigning both public and private IP to the server

Tags: networking, web-hosting

I recently bought a linux machine from aws. It has a public IP 52.14.xx.xx. When I login to its terminal, I note that it has local IP as well, which is 172.13.xx.xx. After seeing this, two questions have arised in my mind:

1. Does a hosting provider(like aws, digital ocean) assign seperate public IP to each server its customers purchase, like I have got one? If it does, won't it exhaust IPv4 address space too quickly?
2. Does each server lies behind a seperate router and have a local IP like the one above? If it does, I don't understand its significance because anyway we will be using it's public IP.

As I'm a beginner in networking, the doubts may seem to be vague, but I've tried to google them but couldn't get any satisfactory answer. Please clear my doubts over these two points.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Does a hosting provider(like aws, digital ocean) assign seperate public IP to each server its customers purchase, like I have got one?

Yes, that's common – although it depends on hosting provider.

Smaller providers (e.g. Linode, Vultr, DO) just assign the addresses directly. There's a datacenter, there are servers, and each server *itself* has its own public IP address – no NAT or anything.

However, large providers (AWS, GCP, Azure) often have a two-layer system, with public IPv4 addresses instead being DNATed to the servers' private IPs. This is more complex, but also has various advantages:

1. You can have "floating IP addresses" that you can easily move from one server to another, without having to reconfigure the server itself at all – the provider simply changes DNAT rules on the virtual router.
2. You can have servers *without* a public address – e.g. DB servers only accessible from your web servers, but not from the Internet.
3. You can usually customize the network, e.g. partition it – it's often possible to create *multiple* separate networks with different security policies, and configure your "virtual routers" however you want.

I think point #2 is the important one here. At these large providers *you* can decide whether you actually need a public IPv4 address every time you create a server. (Often the public IP comes with an extra charge.)

> If it does, won't it exhaust IPv4 address space too quickly?

Yes, but probably not *exactly* in the way you think.

IP address space is assigned in blocks (ranges). Providers don't draw individual addresses from a worldwide pool each time you set up a server – they must first have already obtained a whole address block, and they only assign addresses from their own blocks.

So the provider always knows exactly how many addresses they currently own, and makes decisions based on that. They can try to get more addresses, or introduce a monthly charge for each public address, or discounts for users who go IPv6-only, or such. You'll notice that Amazon charges [by the hour](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/) if it thinks you're "wasting" the address you got.

It's true that eventually the provider will run out of IPv4 addresses and will need to acquire more blocks, and *that* will contribute to the shortage. Indeed nowadays we're so short on addresses that most providers can no longer obtain new IPv4 blocks in the usual way – they must buy them from an existing owner. (For example, Amazon AWS has been collecting absolutely massive blocks – it even has whole /9's and /8's!)

Comment: Hey @user1686, you gave a very decent explanation. But I'm still thinking about the exhaustion of address space if there are almost thousands of providers in the world with every provider doing the same thing, assigning public IPs to each server. Is there any good resource to study this thing, because I cannt find one.

Comment: This looks like that every device in a local network, apart from local IP, can be assigned a public IP which is directly acessible from internet. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, you can assign any kind of address to any device – there's really nothing different about how public addresses work. So as long as you _have_ the address, you can assign it to a laptop, or to a printer, or whatever else.